# how to create a multi database search in xpage?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

I've been experiencing a lot of headache for this issue I'm in. I need to create a multi-database search in xpage, this search functions like a mini google in xpage where if I type, for example,"test" all databases with the same name or contains a title with test will display. I've already looked with the Openntf Project http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Xpages%20Multi%20Database%20Search%20Custom%20Control this seems to solve my problem but unfortunately I'm encountering some error and I'm not a java specialist so I'm still waiting for the creator of the project to reply. So if you know something or tricks to do this kind of stuff its really appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can use the Hyper Search feature from the org.openntf.domino API. No experience with it yet, but seen it and it's pretty impressive: https://github.com/OpenNTF/org.openntf.domino/wiki/OpenNTF-Hyper-Search

Comment: thanks, I'll be checking it out Mark.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

[Plugin to client's sidebar](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Xpages%20Multi%20Database%20Search%20Custom%20Control)

[Custom control for XPages](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Multi-Database%20Search%20Plugin)

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, the first is nice but I don't see how can I use it with xpages. The second link is the one I'm currently using and studying but I do get an error saying "Sorry an error occurred".

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I got it right by playing with the code inside the javascript in this openntf project. ( http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Xpages%20Multi%20Database%20Search%20Custom%20Control) it checks if the database is indexed or not, but unfortunately the script does not detect my indexed dbs so it throws nothing, i just comment out the line that checks it and it works! :)